# Best way to move values from array without for loop in MATLab?

Tags: arrays, matlab, select, move

So I'm trying to separate an array based on the value in one of the columns... the problem is that the for loop I'm using works, but is ridiculously slow. I can get up and have a cup of coffee and eat a sandwich by the time it finishes on my machine.

```
w = waitbar(0,'Separating Velocity values based on processor address');
for i = 1:length(timeDEC);
if paddrDEC(i) == 0
    timeU(i) = timeDEC(i);
    velU(i) = Velocity(i);
end
if paddrDEC(i) == 1
    timeV(i) = timeDEC(i);
    velV(i) = Velocity(i);
end
waitbar(i/length(timeDEC),w);
end
close(w);
```

The processor address is binary, so there are only 2 options (U and V) and I need the appropriate time value to go with them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try logical indexing, like this:

```
timeU = timeDEC(paddrDEC==0);
velU = Velocity(paddrDEC==0);

timeV = timeDEC(paddrDEC==1);
velV = Velocity(paddrDEC==1);
```

Comment: This was perfect. It gets the job done in about 5% of the time.

Comment: @MattS. Glad it helped and welcome on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score -3):

You can use lookup splitting. It is very fast.

Here is an example using it in C#:

```
IList<int> list = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 };

var lookup = list.ToLookup(num => num % 2 == 0);

IEnumerable<int> trueList = lookup[true];

IEnumerable<int> falseList = lookup[false];
```

The idea is that you can split a list based on a predicate (true and false scenario).

Comment: This is a **MATLAB** question, not a C# question. -1.  This also doesn't answer the OP's question as you are using data that was not part of the original problem.

Comment: @rayryeng: Who told you that I wanted to present a complete solution to his/her problem? I have presented here only the idea of using the lookup data structure so he/she can adjust it to his/her domain problem. You attitude was not nice.

Comment: I apologize if my attitude wasn't nice, but you presented an answer using a methodology that is fundamentally different than what was asked.  The OP asked how to do it in MATLAB.  You providing a solution in C# has no benefit to the OP.

Comment: OK, no problem with that. Have a nice day.